# .NET Regex to match repeated character

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to use .NET regular expressions to detect cases where a string has 5 or more characters and the only character in the string is the same.  So these would be seen as matches:

> - 0000000000000
> - ZZZZZZZZZ
> - AAAAAA

But these wouldn't:

> - 000000A000000
> - ZZZZZZ ZZZ  Z
> - AA

Is there a regular expression that could detect this pattern?

Comment: It is easy with `^(.)\1{4}$`

Answer (score 3):

Wiktor was close, but his will only match exactly 5 characters. Sounds like you want 5 *or more*. So what I'd use is

`^(.)\1{4,}$`

The `(.)\1` will capture exactly one character. The `{4,}` specifies that the one character is then repeated 4 or more times. Wrapping it all in `^` and `$` means the string starts immediately before that and ends immediately after, so nothing else is allowed to come before or after it.